# How can I make my font size look good on various devices? Different viewport for iPad and iPhone in UIWebView

Tags: ios, mobile, uiwebview, viewport, meta-tags

I have a page with a lot of text and a couple pictures (like a news article) that I want to display in a way that looks good for both a tablet-sized device and a phone-sized device.

What I do right now is make Scale to Fit = YES and have my html have the meta tag

```
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0'/>
```

but the font size is really too small on the iPad. I tried to resolve it by making initial-scale=2.0 but now it looks huge on the iPhone and even on the galaxy tablet.

How can I deal with varying device sizes and have the font size appear in a way that looks good all on devices?

Perhaps a better question is how can I make UIWebView wrap-text again after I zoom in?

Comment: Maybe <a href="http://fittextjs.com/">this</a> helps you

Comment: From the page: 'Oh, and don't you dare let us catch you using FitText on paragraph text. This is for gigantic display text only!' Thanks for trying though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would keep the scale the same at 1.0, but increase the text size as soon as there is more space available on larger screens. You can achieve this using css media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    /* Styles, for example to increase font size */
    body { font-size: 120%; }
}
```

This will increase the body font size to 120% when displayed on a device with a screen width > 768 (iPad portrait width). You can use multiple of these rules for different widths of course.

W3 has the official [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) specification.

Comment: Perhaps using em's is better...?